# How to create a master page for SharePoint application and add sitemap to it?

Tags: master-page

I am new to SharePoint,can anyone tell me how can i create a master page in my SharePoint application and add sitemap to it?

I am using Visual Studio 2012.
I saw many links however things didn't worked out for me?

Comment: which version & edition of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: sharepoint 2010 sp1

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [following technet Visual Studio 2012/2013 solution](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/SharePoint-20102013-16bb6414) as a starter project for provisioning a sample master page. Edit the master page and add the code sitemap code using the [following post](http://www.sharepointninja.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=56)